# Safari can't open Tomcat localhost

Tags: tomcat, safari

I have the following URL `http://www.example.localhost:8080/` which in Chrome works fine, Safari however says that it can't find the server. How to I open that URL in Safari, I tried changing localhost with `127.0.0.1`, `0.0.0.0` but it isn't working.

I'm running Tomcat 8 from IntelliJ.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't intended to work.  Chrome is is resolving *.localhost to localhost internally.  Either edit your /etc/hosts to point www.example.localhost to 127.0.0.1 or remove the "www.example" from your configuration in IntelliJ.

Answer (score 0):

First :
Go to your System Preferences and enable Web Sharing.

Second:
Check if httpd has started :
ps -eaf | grep httpd
if not :
sudo httpd -k restart

Thirdly:
Check if you have the right access to the folder.
chmod 755

If you are using php, maybe this link can help you.
[Enabling php on Mac OS X Client](http://labs.hoffmanlabs.com/node/1462)